# how do I add an extra Dialog Widget close button to a jquery ui Dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

the standard code to close the window with the X on the top right is this:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button>
```

I need to add a "Close" button at the bottom of the modal popup window.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can visit the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) page, which also has other customizations along with the default functionality.

We also can customize how the display should be. The Dialog in jQuery has `.button` property for which we can create our own customized buttons.

Here is the js for buttons

```
buttons: {
     submit: function(){
      //write your code for submission
     },
     close: function(){
         $(this).dialog('close');
     }
```

This has to be embedded in the dialog method of jQuery.

Here is the fiddle that should answer your question

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UC4y3/)**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the dialog with the buttons option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [ { text: "Close", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ] });
```

Or set the buttons after initialization:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", [ { text: "Close", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ] );
```